# DropDownListFor "the value is invalid" when setting navigation property

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, razor, drop-down-menu, asp.net-mvc-5

I am attempting to set a navigation property (foreign key) based on the return value from a DropDownList.

I have the following data model:

(Some properties and details omitted for the sake of brevity).

An invite, which has a Guid Id and a collection of guests.

```
public class Invite
{
    public Guid InviteId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Guest> Guests { get; set; }
}
```

A guest, with an Invite property linking it to invite.

```
public class Guest
{
    public virtual Invite Invite { get; set; }
}
```

In my DataInitaliser I can correctly build these objects and they are sent to the database, for example:

```
new Invite()
{
    InviteId = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Name = "Bloggs",
    AllDay = false,
    Guests = new List<Guest>()
        {
            new Guest() { GuestId = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName = "Joe", LastName = "Bloggs", Vip = false},
        }
};
```

In my GuestController I build the list of possible invites and add it to the ViewBag for presenting in the view.

```
    void PopulateInvite(object invite)
    {
        var query = db.Invites.Select(i => i).OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToList();

        ViewBag.Invites = new SelectList(query, "InviteId", "Name", invite);
    }
```

I present the list of objects in the Guest View like so:

```
@model Models.Guest
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Invite, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Invite, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Invites, String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Invite)
        </div>
    </div>
```

This correctly displays the expected values from the database.

The problem occurs when I post the values back to the GuestController.

[image]

The Post function for the create is pretty much the standard scaffold.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include="GuestId,FirstName,LastName,Vegetarian,Attending,Vip,Invite")] Guest guest)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            guest.GuestId = Guid.NewGuid();
            db.Guests.Add(guest);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        this.PopulateInvite(guest.Invite);
        return View(guest);
    }
```

I've dug into the cause a little bit here and I think I understand the underlying problem. My function `PopulateInvite`, places `InviteId` into the collection which is a Guid, this is returned as a String (not a Guid?) which cannot be converted into an Invite object.

```
"The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'Models.Invite' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."
```

I did try changing my PopulateInvite collection so its populated with an actual Invite object like so:

```
    void PopulateInvite(object invite)
    {
        var query = db.Invites.Select(i => i).OrderBy(i => i.Name).ToList().Select(i => 
            {
                return new
                {
                    Invite = new Invite() { InviteId = i.InviteId },
                    Name = i.Name
                };
            });

        ViewBag.Invites = new SelectList(query, "Invite", "Name", invite);
    }
```

However this also fails with the same error as above, confusingly I am returned a String representation of the object, instead of the actual object itself.

```
ModelState["Invite"].Value.RawValue
{string[1]}
    [0]: "Models.Invite"
```

So...what is the correct way to set way to set the navigation property based on the post from the form?

Should I act before `ModelState.IsValid` to change the Guid into an actual Invite object?

As this [tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc) from asp.net suggests, should I add a property to hold an InviteId, instead of using an invite object? In the sample `Department` is unused so I don't really understand why it has been added - am I missing something?

```
public class Course
{
    public int DepartmentID { get; set; }

    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Some other better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer was in the actual tutorial I linked in the question. I needed to add an `InviteId` field to act as the foreign key then the actual object acts as the navigation property, as explained below both are required (not just one as I was using it).

[Creating an Entity Framework Data Model for an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

> The StudentID property is a foreign key, and the corresponding
>   navigation property is Student. An Enrollment entity is associated
>   with one Student entity, so the property can only hold a single
>   Student entity (unlike the Student.Enrollments navigation property you
>   saw earlier, which can hold multiple Enrollment entities).
>
> The CourseID property is a foreign key, and the corresponding
>   navigation property is Course. An Enrollment entity is associated with
>   one Course entity.
>
> Entity Framework interprets a property as a foreign key property if
>   it's named  (for
>   example, StudentID for the Student navigation property since the
>   Student entity's primary key is ID). Foreign key properties can also
>   be named the same simply  (for example,
>   CourseID since the Course entity's primary key is CourseID).

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind a complex component like model.Invite in a DropDownListFor:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Invite, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Invites, String.Empty
```

You need to put a singular value like a int from ID. Try to replace the code above to:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Invite.InviteID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Invites, String.Empty
```